# Is there a way to save or edit Crystal reports in version 8.5 format in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report file I need make a tiny edit in. It was created in/for Crystal Reports 8.5.

I can open it in Visual Studio 2008 but saving the file updates the file version and the report fails with the third part software that reads it (Actinic).

I don't know much about Crystal reports. Is there a way I can edit the file without breaking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a copy of Crystal 8.5. The later versions are not backwards compatible.